# Solr index multiple project similtanous

Tags: indexing, deployment, solr

I have a Solr web server that starting with this cmd

```
 java -jar start.jar
```

I need to use this instance of solr to index differents projects.

Example

**Machine1 that work with DataBase1 to index some table in this database.**

**Machine2 that work with DataBase2 to index some table in this database.**

All this machine should use the Solr web server to  index and search data.

How to do that **without restarting solr server** to support other project to be indexed?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to restart Solr because, as you said, it is a server and a service.

Depending on your query and schema requirements, you could load all databases into a single core or, at the other extreme,  you could have a dedicated core for each datasource.

In any case, once you decided the appropriate Solr configuration, you will start it and there won't be any need to restart it